# Asymptotic expansion of the integral $\int_2^T \frac{\cosh ^{-1}(T-x+2)}{\ln(x)} \, dx$

Tags: integration, asymptotics

I was trying to expand the above integral using integration by parts in order to get an asymptotic expansion:

$$
\int_2^T \frac{\cosh ^{-1}(T-x+2)}{\ln(x)} \, dx
$$

which I hoped like Li($x$) I could get a pretty good approximation in two or three iterations and hopefully easily determine a Big (O) or something like that.

To help me along I used Maple:

> with(IntegrationTools)
>
> VIU := Int(arccosh(T+2-x)/ln(x), x = 2 .. T)
>
> Parts(VIU, 1/ln(x))

I get:

[image: oneoutput]

Then, another iteration at the Maple input:

> VIU2 := Int(-(-(T+2-x)*arccosh(T+2-x)+sqrt(T+1-x)*sqrt(T+3-x))/(ln(x)^2*x), x = 2 .. T)
>
> Parts(VIU2, -(T+2-x)*arccosh(T+2-x)+sqrt(T+1-x)*sqrt(T+3-x))

gives:

[image: two]

Something must be wrong as both passes give the same constant output.

Can this function be expanded using integration by parts?

Comment: In what sense do you want an asymptotic expansion? Maybe $T \to +\infty$?

Comment: @Antonio Vargas I mean in the same sense $\int_2^x \frac{t}{\log t}dt$ is calculated over an interval in this case T not x for $\int_2^T \frac{\cosh ^{-1}(T-x+2)}{\ln(x)} \, dx$. Afterall this seems to be the only work around to approximate by integration by parts that function so I thought the same would be here.

Comment: So do you want a large-$T$ approximation or a small-$T$ approximation or...?

Comment: @Antonio Vargas I want a large-T approximation. Looking a bit more there seems to be several methods apart from Integration by parts - www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~gajjar/MATH34011/notes/34011_note2.pdf - but I think given the difficulty of the integral Integration by parts is the most approachable.